# Extending AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer and using beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC/Security project where I extend AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer. Also, I use two own filters which I can successfully add behind the springSecurityFilterChain. Everything's fine.

Now, I want to use a bean (java.util.Properties, myAppProperties) which contains an URL pattern among other settings.

If I define this bean in the class below, the method `myAppProperties` is **executed twice**. During the first run (when also `afterSpringSecurityFilterChain` is executed), the application context is null. `myAppProperties` is used via method call, and everything run fine. Other classes in my project can use the bean, too. I think it's because during the second execution of `myAppProperties()` the application context is initialized (not null).

**Problem:** if I move `myAppProperties` to another configuration class (`MyAppBeans`), where a lot of other beans are defined, it comes to a `NullPointerException` when calling `myAppProperties().getProperty`, because the bean is not injected at this time.

I suppose, the reason for this is that `afterSpringSecurityFilterChain` is executed before the root application context is initialized.

Is it impossible to use beans within an extension of `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`?

```java
package com.application.springBoot;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;

@Configuration
//@Import(MyAppBeans.class)   // no success if active
public class myAppSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer implements
        ApplicationContextAware
{

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(myAppSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.class.getName());
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Bean
    public Properties myAppProperties() throws IOException
    {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(myAppSecurityConfigurer.class.getResourceAsStream("/myAppConfig.properties"));
        logger.info("Application Context für myAppProperties: {}", appContext == null ? "null" : appContext.hashCode());
        return p;
    }

    /*                            +++++++++++  doesn't work
    @Autowired(required = true)
    Properties myAppProperties;     // is null
    */

    @Override
    protected void afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext)
    {
        logger.info("eigene Filter hinter der SpringSecurityFilterChain eintragen ...");
        try
        {
            String[] filters = {"prepareRequestFilter", "responseTextXmlFilter"};

            FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration;
            String filterUrlPattern = myAppProperties().getProperty("myApp.filterPattern");

            for (String filter : filters)
            {
                registration = servletContext.addFilter(filter, DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
                registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, filterUrlPattern);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.error("FEHLER: ", e);
            System.err.println("FEHLER: " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException
    {
        appContext=ac;
        logger.debug("Application Context: {} {}", ac==null?"":ac.hashCode(), ac);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` is something different then the application context and you are basically using it wrong. The class is a `WebApplicationInitializer` which is used to register all needed components like the `DispatcherServlet`, `ContextLoaderListener` etc. there is no `ApplicationContext` at that point. Just load the properties yourself (as you are doing now, basically the `@Bean` is useless).

Comment: @M.Deinum - ok, that's something I already thoght about. I'll remove `@Configuration` , `@Import` , `implements ApplicationContextAware` and read the properties the classic way.

What do you mean when you say "basically using it wrong" ? Shall I  add my filters elsewhere?

Comment: No that was about the fact that it is also `@Configurable` and containing a `@Bean` definition.